# Check if Any conforms to Hashable and get hash value

Tags: swift, hashable

I want to get the hash value of an `Any` object that conforms to Hashable.

However, with this code:

```swift
    let anyValue: Any
    //...
    if let h = anyValue as? Hashable {
        return h.hashValue
    }
```

I'm getting this error

> `Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `AnyHashable` instead of `Hashable`, which is the type erased version of the `Hashable` protocol created to resolve that specific error you are encountering.

```
if let h = anyValue as? AnyHashable {
```

Comment: This gives me an error: `Cast from 'Error' to unrelated type 'AnyHashable' always fails`

Comment: @BenLeggiero that's a fully separate problem. OP was using `Any`, not `Error`. Feel free to ask a new question with your different, but slightly connected problem.

Comment: Thanks! That actually pointed me to a solution: `(error as Any) as? AnyHashable`